# SQLite Auto Increment Error

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, sqlite

I have been having with problem with running my Android app as I've encountered an SQLite problem of,

> SQLite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

I have followed the advice of others from various forums and websites and they all say to change the ROWID alias of INTEGER PRIMARY KEY to something else. My current database schema is as seen below but it still comes up with an error during deployment.

I would be grateful if someone could give me some further advice on this.

```
     public partial class CompletedExercise
     {
         [NotNull]
         public Int32 workoutID { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Int32 exerciseID { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public String compDate { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Int32 setNumber { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Int32 repetitions { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Double weight { get; set; }

     }

     public partial class Exercise
     {
         [PrimaryKey]
         public Int32 exerciseID { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public String exerciseName { get; set; }

     }

     public partial class Scheme
     {
         [PrimaryKey]
         public Int32 schemeID { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public String schemeName { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public String schemeDesc { get; set; }

     }

     public partial class Workout
     {
         [PrimaryKey]
         public Int32 workoutID { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public String workoutName { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Int32 schemeID { get; set; }

     }

     public partial class WorkoutExercise
     {
         [NotNull]
         public Int32 workoutID { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Int32 exerciseID { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Int32 sets { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Int32 repetitions { get; set; }

         [NotNull]
         public Double startingWeight { get; set; }

     }
```

Comment: There is no AUTOINCREMENT in the code you've shown.

Comment: Exactly! Why does the error occur then? It errors whether I explicitly declare the ROWID alias of "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" or not.

Comment: The error occurs because the code you've shown is not the code that is actualy executed.

Comment: For some reason, the Exercise table fails as the program executes "create table if not exists \"Exercise\"(\n\"exerciseID\" bigint primary key autoincrement not null ,\n\"exerciseName\" varchar not null )".

I dont understand why the Scheme and Workout tables don't have that autoincrement keyword in them - the scheme is the same for them.

Comment: Then where does the error message come from? In which line of your code does the exception happen?

Comment: I've updated the code - I re-generated it as per the previous scheme. However, whenever there was a compound primary key, there is just [NotNull] now - how will the program now that its a compound PK?